# Printer driver, to copy printed file, to a folder?

Tags: windows, file, printing, copy, driver

Is it possible to create a printer driver; to copy the file selected for print to a predefined folder?

or alternatively is there a anything out there that already does this?

I realise that I will need to use the Windows Driver Development Kit, but it would be nice to know if this is possible/necessary.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't. You receive the filename in the driver but you don't get the full path. So you cannot know which file is printing. But you can save a bitmap output of what the applications is printing. Look at print examples in WinDDK.